# What is the syntax for scanner be utilized to read from files in JAVA?

Tags: java, file, syntax

I am trying to set up a stream from a file that is entered into the method fromFile, yet when I try to access this from within in my method, I get error. How can I fix this.

```
public int[] fromFile(String fileName)
{
    // TO-DO: convert the file to a int[]
    int[] ret = new int [9];
    int i = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName); 

        while (i < 10){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file); //HERE I get FileNotFoundException


        ret [i] = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        i++;


     }
```

Comment: Ensure the PATH of your file is correct?

Comment: The method would be taking new file specified by fileName,each time the method is utilized, so I can't set the path to a specific file.

Comment: *I get error* is not a problem description unless you tell us what that *error* is specifically. It's on the screen, right in front of you. There is absolutely no reason for you to fail to include that information in your post here, so we have it as well. This question also shows absolutely no research effort, as there are at least several dozen questions here already about Java and Scanner and reading files. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to become familiar with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here.

Comment: I literally wrote filenotfound exception in the code. The whole point in including the code is that you ought to read it. Just because questions on Scanner exist doesn't mean they adress the problem at hand. Most scanner posts have nothing to do with files.Think before commenting.

Comment: This is what the exception **really** looks like: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: foobarblah (No such file or directory)`. It shows the file name. *Of the file that doesn't exist*. To fix it, make sure that either you pass a different file name of one that does exist, or you create the file before running the code again. It's not that hard - the error is very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few issues with your code; first, you need to close the `Scanner` after you use it when it wraps a `File` (or you leak file handles) here I use a `try-with-resources`. Second, you can check if the file exists and is readable by calling `File.canRead()` before you try to read it. Also, you can use `Scanner.nextInt()` instead of manually parsing your values (and you should probably call `Scanner.hasNextInt()` first). Something like,

```
public static int[] fromFile(String fileName) {
    int[] ret = new int[9];
    int i = 0;

    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.canRead()) {
        try {
            System.err.printf("Cant read file at %s%n", file.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (i < 10 && s.hasNextInt()) {
            ret[i] = s.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```